# phpredis is not installing in the windows 8.1 64bit

Tags: php, redis, installation, 64-bit

I am a web designer and have a limited knowledge about the PHP and for a project a have to install phpredis.
I am running the windows 8.1 64 bit and php 5.5.11;

In order to use that i install redis and then try to install phpredis.

I downloaded php_redis.dll and php_igbinary.dll from "www.char101.github.io/phpredis/". i try to use the git library of phpredis. but that not work either. i am sure that redis server is running because its process is showing in the task manager. i tell u what i did

1. Download the file from "http://char101.github.io/phpredis/"
2. Put the files in the php/ext folder
3. add the path in the php.ini file

but still I am getting these error please have a look and try to solve it.
can't put the image in question so put in a external URL .
http://www.datazen.in/error.png

Comment: Which version of PHP are you running? 32 bit? 64 bit?

Comment: my php Architecture is x86 and i am running xampp.with php 5.5.11

Comment: The page you're linking to does not have a version for PHP 5.5. [This support thread](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/351) seems to have some links to binaries for 5.5 though, although I've not tested them myself.